# url links to SSRS reports

Tags: silverlight, reporting-services, uri

I have a sql server which hosts three groups of reports. Rather than linking to the reports manager page which shows all three report groups I decided I would like to link directly to a report group.

Here's the URI which i'm passing (this is coming from a silverlight usercontrol with a button click event)
[http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fConveyor+Reports&ViewMode=List](http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=/Conveyor%20Reports&ViewMode=List)
but instead it sends me to http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx

In that link ^ i'm trying to link into the "Conveyor Reports" group directly. But the end result is always redirecting me to Reports Manager homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my formatting to

```
http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=/Conveyor%20Reports
```

and it worked.